# Why does virtualbox show only 32 bit option on 64 bit machine and 32 bit os doesn't work

Tags: windows, virtualbox, lenovo-laptop

I have a 64 bit AMD computer and was trying to install Virtualbox. However there were only 32 bit options for creating virtual machines. I googled a fix and it said to disable Hyper-v and enable virtualization. I went to windows features to disable hyper-v, but it was already disabled. But as for the virtualization, I couldn't find it in the BIOS anywhere.

How would I enable virtualization?

Comment: No it is not a duplicate; it is different

Comment: Not different at all. The answer should be made more generic, but AMD SVM and Intel VT-x are equivalent features – despite manufacturers having different names for them.

Comment: There is also an answer that specifically mentions updating the BIOS and making sure virtualisation is enabled, which is exactly what you did.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup From the accepted answer of the duplicate, "For Intel x64: VT-x (Intel Virtualization Technology) and VT-d are both enabled", which is what you ended up doing.  So this is indeed a duplicate.  The community is a better position to determine if something is a duplicate.  Three highly experienced users all agree this was a duplicate.

Comment: ok. but it won't let me delete it

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup - This question will not be deleted on purpose.  There is absolutely no reason to delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to update the BIOS, and then to go the BIOS and enable the AMD SVM/ Intel VT-x setting. Now it works perfectly.